# How to switch on syntax highlighting for python snippet?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I tried to highlight some code in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154056/33055), by inserting an explicit

```
<!-- language-all: python -->
```

at the top of the file.

I also tried `<!-- language: python -->` just before the block of code, and have replaced `python` by `py` (as the latter is mentioned on [meta-stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)) in both.

None of these seem to trigger highlighting of the python code. I am doing something wrong, but what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was `python`, which tells it to use the syntax highlighting associated with the tag [python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), which for some reason was set to "none". I changed it now, so both the methods you described will work. In the future, you can also directly specify a language from the list in that meta post (instead of specifying a tag), but you need to prefix it with `lang`, e.g. `<!-- language: lang-py -->`.

See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thanks, I read the syntax-highlighting for code in the [help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), but looked at the example ( `<!-- language: c# -->`) more than closely reading the text and follow the links. And I know this had worked for me (but that was on [so])